Fonts not identified as fixed width by FontBook
I have downloaded a monospace font, but when I open FontBook and click on the left side on "Fixed width", the new font does not show. It shows up however under "All Fonts", and I can see that the characters do have the same width.


The font which I have added, was downloaded here: https://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/osdn.jp/users/8/8642/genjyuugothic-20150607.zip
I have unzipped the file, selected all the TTF, and then did "open with FontBook" from the context menu.

The criterion that Apple uses for the "Design Style" property in "Smart Collections" is undocumented.
However, it's likely to use the PANOSE data in the font, which is used exactly to describe the visual characteristics of the typeface.
From a quick look at your font, the PANOSE data is set to "Normal irregular", rather than the expected "Monospaced".

So that may be the cause of it.
However, I have had problems getting my own (designed) fonts to appear in the "English" collection in Fontbook; but following a OS install and reboot, they are now showing. So it may be a font cache that needs clearing, or just a reboot.

I think that's it, because another monospace font which I installed afterwards was listed well. Just being curious: What did you do to find the PANOSE data of the fonts which I have installed?

@user1934428 I used FontLab, a font editing tool.
